# Can I say that :$\zeta(-3.9901894525-i 0.0001710810718)$ a non trivial zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, roots, riemann-zeta

I have performed some computations in wolfram alpha for $z=\log (cosx)+i\log (sinx) $ at $x = 1.552 \cdots$ I got this [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta%28log%28cosx%29%2Bilog%28sinx%29%29+,+x%3D1.55229922887) , Really i don't have enough competence to know what is the real diffrence between Non zero and trivial zero because as show above in the titled question $z=-3.99\cdots+0.0001\cdots $ has a real part's almost is trivial zero which is :the integer $x=-4$.

**My question here** :Can I say that  :$\zeta(-3.9901894525-i 0.0001710810718$ )  is a non zero ?

**Note:**   At a least I would like to know how do i can considerating it

Thank you for any help !!!!

Comment: Being a zero means you get exactly 0. Something small but not equal to zero is a non zero.

Comment: The only zeros of $\zeta$ with negative real part are trivial. So $-3.99+\text{whatever}$ is not a zero.

Comment: I meant a non trivial zero , as u said small but not equal zero as shown in wolfram alpha after some computation what i did out

Comment: Of course a parameter very close to a trivial zero is going to give a value very close to zero.  It's an analytic function.

Comment: mayeb it's just an approach

Comment: @Wojowu, but trivial zero are not complex numbers

Comment: Real numbers are complex numbers.

Comment: but  we can't always getting a parameter very close to zero by adding any negative trivial zero as example :$\zeta(-121.9901894525-i 0.0001710810718$ ) is not close to zero , this is realy what i w'd like investigate about it

Comment: There is a *proof* that $\zeta(x+iy)\ne0$ when $x<0$, except for the trivial zeros $x=-2k,y=0$. So your value is definitely not zero.

Comment: ok, thanks for that

Comment: @user51189, the zeta function has a very large derivative down there - it's still "close," it just flies away.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you go back to the paper in which the Riemann zeta function was introduced.

http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/EZeta.pdf

Right off the bat (first paragraph of page 4 by footer numbers - NB the definition of ξ a few lines before), it was established that any nontrivial zeroes must have a real part between 0 and 1.  If you're going to be tackling the most notorious open problem in mathematics, you should probably endeavor in humility to read and understand not only that paper, but reams and reams of further material on the subject.